# AngularJS add qualification app, similar to a toDo app

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating a simple angular app where you input some educational results and I then want to add the qualification to a list, similar to a simple to do list.

I've create a fiddle with where I am at the moment: http://jsfiddle.net/shannabarnard/nykm5857/1/

What I want to do now is add the qualification which is a combination of the $scope.ibLevel, $scope.ibSubject and $scope.ibGrade and call it $scope.ibQualification and this will be the item I add to the list. Can any one solve this for me or suggest a better approach to the one I am taking?

```
function($scope) {
    $scope.ibLevel = [
      {level:'Higher'},
      {level:'Standard'}
    ];
    $scope.ibSubject = [
      {subject:'Biology'},
      {subject:'Chemistry'},
      {subject:'Maths'},
      {subject:'Further Maths'},
      {subject:'Human Biology'},
      {subject:'Physics'},
    ];
    $scope.ibGrade = [
      {grade:'7'},
      {grade:'6'},
      {grade:'5'}
    ];
  }
```

Comment: Do yo want to add them as a list?

Comment: yes but grouped, so an ibQualification would as an example be, Level: Higher, Subject: Biology, Grade: 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the fiddle for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nykm5857/4/)

Its a not good practice to add a selected property to an Array object. If you see this sample we have new scope object named "selected" that carries the selected values.

Controller:

```
$scope.addibQualification = function(){
    var qualification = angular.copy($scope.selected);
    $scope.selected = {};
}
```

Html:

```
  <div ng-repeat="option in ibLevel" class="btn-group">
      <input type="radio" ng-model="selected.ibLevel" value="{{option.level}}">{{option.level}}
    </div>
    {{selected.ibLevel}}

    <br class="clearfix">

    <span class="button-group-header">IB subject:</span>

    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selected.ibSubject" ng-options="subject.subject for subject in ibSubject">
      <option value="">-- choose subject --</option>
    </select>
    {{selected.ibSubject}}

    <br class="clearfix">

    <span class="button-group-header">Grade:</span>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <div ng-repeat="option in ibGrade" class="btn-group">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="selected.ibGrade" value="{{option.grade}}">{{option.grade}}
      </div>
    </div>
    {{selected.ibGrade}}
    <br class="clearfix">

    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block add-qual-btn" ng-click="addibQualification()">+ Add qualification</button>

    <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
        <thead>
            <th>Level</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
        </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="qualification in qualifications">
        <td>{{qualification.ibLevel}}</td>
        <td>{{qualification.ibSubject.subject}}</td>
        <td>{{qualification.ibGrade}}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with Karthik's approach, as it can be simplified and the ng-repeat loading the qualifications does not work in the jsfiddle provided. The requirement was to be able to push multiple qualifications not just one.

Here is a more concise, simple solution, that actually works: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nykm5857/6/)

JS

```
function demoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.qualification = {};
    $scope.qualifications = [];
    $scope.formSettings = {
        levels: [
            'Higher',
            'Standard'
        ],
        subjects: [   
            'Biology',
            'Chemistry',
            'Math',
            'Further Maths',
            'Human Biology',
            'Physics',
        ],
        grades: [
            '7',
            '6',
            '5',
        ]
    };
    $scope.addQualification = function () {
        $scope.qualifications.push(angular.copy($scope.qualification));
    };
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>

  <div ng-controller="demoCtrl">
    <span class="button-group-header">Level:</span>

        <div ng-repeat="level in formSettings.levels" class="btn-group">
            <input type="radio" ng-model="qualification.level" value="{{level}}" />{{level}}
        </div>

        <br class="clearfix">

        <span class="button-group-header">Subject:</span>

        <select class="form-control" ng-model="qualification.subject" ng-options="subject for subject in formSettings.subjects">
          <option value="">-- choose subject --</option>
        </select>
        {{subject}}

        <br class="clearfix">

        <span class="button-group-header">Grade:</span>

        <div class="btn-group">
          <div ng-repeat="grade in formSettings.grades" class="btn-group">
            <input type="radio" ng-model="qualification.grade" value="{{grade}}">{{grade}}
          </div>
        </div>
        <br class="clearfix">

        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block add-qual-btn" ng-click="addQualification()">+ Add qualification</button>

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="qualification in qualifications">
                <p>Level: {{qualification.level}}, Subject: {{qualification.level}}, Grade: {{qualification.grade}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>

</div>
```